# MySQL combing results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `users` and I have a simple search query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   users 
WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' 
LIMIT 10
```

I also have another table called `follows` which basically is a list of users being followed by other users. I modified the above query to search only within what particular user is following:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM   follows
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = follows.following_id
WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' AND follows.follower_id = 18
LIMIT 10
```

Most of the times, the query above only returns couple of results (because I am not search the entire users table).

What I want to do is combine the above 2 queries, to return a MAXIMUM of 10 results of usernames matching a certain string with first listing the user's following, and then search the entire table of users.

I already have a solution but it requires doing this at application level by first running the 2nd query, then first, and coming the two. Is there a way I can do all of this in 1 query?

Thanks

Comment: The usual drill: table schema, sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to search the entire user table, but order the results so that followers show up first. It's a little bit hard to understand what you want without schema, sample data, and output, but something like

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM   users
LEFT JOIN follows ON users.id = follows.following_id
WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%'
ORDER BY follows.follower_id = 18 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Notice that I used a `LEFT JOIN` in order to get all of the users. A different way would be to `UNION` the results of the two tables and wrap in a `SELECT`. I don't know why you would do it this way given the other option, but it would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT users.* 
    FROM   follows
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = follows.following_id
    WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' AND follows.follower_id = 18
    LIMIT 10

    UNION

    SELECT * 
    FROM   users 
    WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' 
    LIMIT 10
) AS u
LIMIT 10
```

**edit**

Since the second one is working for you, I thought I throw a variation up using `UNION ALL`, which can be faster than `UNION` because it does not remove duplicate rows. You would have to make sure there were no duplicates yourself, which we can do like this

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT users.* 
    FROM   follows
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = follows.following_id
    WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' AND follows.follower_id = 18
    LIMIT 10

    UNION ALL

    SELECT users.* 
    FROM   follows
    INNER JOIN users ON users.id = follows.following_id
    WHERE  username LIKE 'rya%' AND follows.follower_id != 18
    LIMIT 10
) AS u
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: 2nd query much much faster though. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Good, I'm glad I put put queries in. Do you have follower_id indexed? I suspect that with the right indexes the first query could be plenty fast.